# How to implement JQuery easing into this window scroll movement function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, easing-functions, jquery-easing

With this code I've been able to capture the mousewheel movement and apply it to the horizontal scroll bars instead of the vertical default.

```
$('html').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
   window.parent.scrollBy(-120 * delta, 0);
   return false;
});
```

Is there any way that I could add this jQuery easing animation to the scroll movement?

```
// t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
jQuery.extend( jQuery.easing, {
   easeInOutBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
        if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158; 
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*(t*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t - s)) + b;
        return c/2*((t-=2)*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t + s) + 2) + b;
   }
});
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

i think what you need is the scrollTo plugin.  seems to fit the bill, though i haven't used it personally.  basically should be able to call it like this

```
$.scrollTo( -120*delta, {duration:1000,easing:'easeInOutBack',axis:'x'} )
```

find the plugin demo [here](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/).  the jquery plugin site appears to be offline currently, but when its back up, the plugin can be found [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)